# Javascript code work fine on google chrome but not working on mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a slider on my website but it is working fine on google chrome but not working on mozilla firefox. Please help me to fix this problem.

javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        var currentPosition = 0;
        var slideWidth = 230;
        var slides = $('.clienttestslide');
        var numberOfSlides = slides.length;
        var slideShowInterval;
        var speed = 3000;


        slideShowInterval = setInterval(changePosition, speed);

        slides.wrapAll('<div id="clienttestslideHolder"></div>')

        slides.css({ 'float' : 'left' });

        $('#clienttestslideHolder').css('width', slideWidth * numberOfSlides);


        function changePosition() {
            if(currentPosition == numberOfSlides - 1) {
                currentPosition = 0;
            } else {
                currentPosition++;
            }
            moveSlide();
        }


        function moveSlide() {
                $('#clienttestslideHolder')
                  .animate({'marginLeft' : slideWidth*(-currentPosition)});
        }

    });
</script>
```

html code:

```
<div id="clienttest">
                 <div id="clienttestwindow">
                        <div class="clienttestslide">
                            <div class="statementup">
                                <div class="statementdown">
                                    <p>I recently booked a tour with 
Green Apple Travel around Kathmandu. This is the second time I use their 
services.
I have traveled worldwide for the last 50 years and have been in 
business with dozens of t...   </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>



                           <div class="anno_textarea_text">
                               <p style="margin-left:20px; color:#e30715;"><strong>Client Name</strong></p>

                           </div>

                        </div>


                        <div class="clienttest">
                           <div class="statementup">
                                <div class="statementdown">
                                    <p>I recently booked a tour with 
Green Apple Travel around Kathmandu. This is the second time I use their 
services.
I have traveled worldwide for the last 50 years and have been in 
business with dozens of t...   </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>




                           <div class="anno_textarea_text">
                               <p style="margin-left:20px; color:#e30715;"><strong>Client Name</strong></p>

                           </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="clienttestslide">
                          <div class="statementup">
                                <div class="statementdown">
                                    <p>I recently booked a tour with 
Green Apple Travel around Kathmandu. This is the second time I use their 
services.
I have traveled worldwide for the last 50 years and have been in 
business with dozens of t...   </p>
                               </div>
                           </div>




                           <div class="anno_textarea_text">
                               <p style="margin-left:20px; color:#e30715;"><strong>Client Name</strong></p>

                           </div>
                        </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
```

Slider is working perfectly on chrome but when i tested it on mozilla firefox it is not working and shows blank on it. I hope someone will be available for the help. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you getting any errors on the firefox console?

Comment: @AndrewLyndem No i haven't received any error on firefox.

Comment: @magreenberg Css is working fine as it is working perfectly on google chrome.

Comment: @Bibek Let me more clear. I can't recreate the error given the code you provided. So unless you have a working site or `jsfiddle`, we cant help.